# Faster alternatives for Electron's IPC module

Tags: performance, electron

I'm writing an Electron application which needs to send quite some data every ~25ms from the renderer to a separate Node process started in the main process with the native `fork` module.

The data looks like this: `[{ x: int, y: int }, ...]`, with about 1000 points in it (and a bit more information than shown here for brevity).

I started using `ipc.send` in the renderer process but it has quite a serious performance penalty: 4.25ms for every `ipc.send`.

So I looked into starting a WebSocket with the `ws` npm package in the forked Node process, and sending the data over the WebSocket with JSON. This was a lot better. Even improved it further by using `avsc` instead of parsing to JSON (from ~4ms to ~1ms).

So the WebSocket solution is working great, but there's a problem: it needs to find a free port and go over the local network. In macOS this also triggers a dialog:

> Do you want the application "x.app" to accept incoming network connections?

This dialog in combination with the trickiness of using the local network is something I'd like to avoid if possible.

**My question is:** does anyone know of a better solution to send data to other processes in Electron that doesn't go over the local network?

Answer (score 6):

> So the WebSocket solution is working great, but there's a problem: it
>   needs to find a free port and go over the local network. In macOS this
>   also triggers a dialog: ...

Are you using a loopback address? Loopback addresses should never require a network confirmation. In my local ws electron projects, I use 127.0.0.1:port instead of localhost, and this bypasses internet security dialogs entirely. You can use other 127.x.x.x addresses, as long as you add the appropriate loopback interface on [Linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444124/how-to-add-a-loopback-interface)/[MacOS](https://blog.felipe-alfaro.com/2017/03/22/persistent-loopback-interfaces-in-mac-os-x/). On Windows, 127.x.x.x are already added by default.

> My question is: does anyone know of a better solution to send data to other processes in Electron that doesn't go over the local network?

Electron can either use IPC, RPC or network-based comm techs. You've already experienced IPC (RPC is very similar). The fastest, in my experience are the network-based techs. My experience was very similar to yours in that websockets blew the competition away. The network-based comm techs should never trigger LAN/WAN/ISP security measures unless they use LAN/WAN/ISP addresses.

Comment: To clarify: never use your computer's network IP or 0.0.0.0 *(which means any interface)*. Localhost is generally fine, but is spoofable because it uses a local DNS lookup.